# Replace all Zeros by Ones in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace

I have a numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[-1,1,-1],[-1,1,1]])
```

My array only contains two different values: -1 and 1. However, I want to replace all 1's by 0 and all -1's by 1. Of course I can loop over my array, check the value of every field and replace it. This will work for sure, but I was looking for a more convenient way to do it.

I am looking for some sort of

```
replace(old, new)
```

function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[-1,1,-1],[-1,1,1]])

# approach 1
a[a == 1] = 0
a[a == -1] = 1

# approach 2
mask = a == 1
a[mask] = 0
a[~mask] = 1

print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is by @Tusamma Sal Sabil, in terms of speed
here is a little improvement on his response:

import numpy as np

```
a = np.array([[-1,1,-1],[-1,1,1]])
mask = a == 1
a[mask] = 0
a[~mask] = 1

#array([[1, 0, 1],
#       [1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: How about `a = np.where(a == 1, 0, 1)`?

Comment: The OP told that we have only 2 options, so the optimization is to use one only mask, the where is a valid alternative, but AFAIK a little bit slower. Thank's

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

sample_arr = np.ones((5,2))
print('Converting an array with ones to zero')
np.where(sample_arr==1, 0, sample_arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `(a == -1 ).astype(np.int32)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
import numpy as np


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.array([[-1,1,-1],[-1,1,1]])
    a[a == 1] = 0
    a[a == -1] = 1
    print(a)
```